# LoRa and LoRaWAN simulator

Tags: lora, lorawan

Which simulator is suitable for energy harvesting in LoRaWAN? Is it possible to use LoRaSIM to simulate energy harvesting aided LoRa?

I tried to use LoRaSIM but I couldn’t find anything related to energy sources and energy harvesting in end nodes.